# Cannot load images once symfony project is deployed on production server

Tags: image, symfony, webpack, deployment, webpack-encore

I'm actually working on the server migration of a Symfony project. I'm new to Symfony so i'm discovering how a Symfony project works at the same time.
The projet use Symfony 4.

I'm stuck at the point where the deployment on the production server works but once on the website side, images and .css files cannot be loaded.
I get the following error in the console : [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUCFz.png)
When I look at the path where images are loaded I get http://domainname/builg/images/imagename.jpg
I have check and the images are well located in the folder public/build/images in the server.

I've tried accessing the images directly by doing a GET request on the search bar but I can't have access whether it is by asking http://domainname/build or http://domainname/public/images

As the project is actually perfectly running on another server and locally on my computer I don't think the issue come from twig or the webpack encore.

I can't see what I've done wrong.

Maybe have I missed something in the configuration phase ? Should I update some path ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using a cache for your assets e.g Cloudflare or Cloudfront?

Comment: Check that public/build/* is readable by user www-data

Comment: I'm not using a cache for the assets. They all are in hard in the folder. The rights on the folder seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Symfony 6 or 5. Please follow these steps:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

npm run build  

OR

yarn run build
```

assets are auto symlink in latest symfony 5 or 6 version. If not then please run this command:

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
```

And try to access `http://domainname/build/images/imagename.jpg`  . Make sure this url is correct with image name and path.

Comment: After having followed those steps, I get to the same point.
My project use Symfony 4. I don't think that the issue come from an asset installation as all images files are in the public/build/images folder. It is as if the cannot be reached because the path is wrong or something else but I can't find what...

Comment: Are symlink and proper user roles added to the public/build folder?

Comment: I do not use symlink as files are hard copied to the folder. As it is well done, I assume that user roles are well defined

Comment: What is your code for loading images in twig file? Is it like this?
`{{ asset('/images/company-logo.png') }}` It should assets folder path rather then public/build path.

Comment: I got this path on the twig.yaml file :
''paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/assets/images': images''